# preventDefault for save popup is working in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

Hi i like to prevent the default behaviour of ctrl+s(save) so i tried the below code

```
jQuery(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey && (e.which == 83)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Ctrl+S");
    return false;
  }
});
```

But this is preventing only in chrome not in firefox.In firefox the save dialog is poping up why is this happening or am i missing something.Any help?

Comment: It works in Firefox/mac. But you do know that mac uses `cmd+s` to save, right? Preventing OS-standard key combos can be very annoying for the user.

Comment: Thanks, in some cases even same OS with different browser will vary in e.which value for same key. ok can you find why in firefox/windows this code is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).bind('keydown', function(event) {
      //19 for Mac Command+S
     if (!( String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase() == 's' && event.ctrlKey) && !(event.which == 19)) return true;

      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("Ctrl-s pressed");
      return false;
   });
});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dpHk9/

**Explanation**

The below code converts unicode number into corresponding character:

```
String.fromCharCode(number) //returns A for 65
```

The below code represents control key:

```
event.ctrlKey
```

On a MAC, `command+s` returns 19

Comment: just with ctrl key alone it is alerting

Comment: somehow, if you use alert, the save dialog pops up, but the alert is also shown. So, replaced alert with console.log. Works fine.

Comment: in chrome, the alert works, console.log did not work

Comment: Thanks i don't want the alert function just to cross check i did that. if you explain the third line it'll be helpful to me

Answer (score 3):

Try this....

```
$(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey && (e.which == 83)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("Ctrl+S");
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
});
```

Using an alert will complete the thread execution, only for the thread to be picked up again once the OK button of the alert is clicked.  I can only imagine that at this point the 'preventDefault' just hasn't been acknowledged by Firefox (even though you're calling this before the alert) and it continues to display the Save As dialog.

I've used a setTimeout to delay the alert by 1 second, although I'm sure using 0 will have the same effect... simply pushing the function (now async) showing the alert to the back of the execution stack, which will allow the browser to complete the execution of the preventDefault.

I know you don't want the 'alert', but thought I'd provide an explanation of the behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the understandable explanation according to the given code. +1